# How to set ItemStyle of content query web part programmatically?

Tags: 2010, content-query-web-part, item-styles

I have added a content query web part from visual studio and I am displaying the data from a document library of root site.

I want to set the ItemStyle property to Title and Description and assigne them respective value i.e. Title=Document Title and Description=Editor.

My code for adding web part is:

```
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1");
            SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
            SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager("SiteAssets/webparts.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
            ContentByQueryWebPart wp = new ContentByQueryWebPart();
            wp.Title = "My web part using OM";                                
            wp.ListGuid = "eff50fad-f899-4e26-a9a4-1b40aedfc9be";                                         
            wp.WebUrl = "~SiteCollection";                
            wp.ItemStyle = "Title and Description";
            webParts.AddWebPart(wp, "Right", 0);
            webParts.SaveChanges(wp);
            web.Update();
            Console.WriteLine("Web part added successfully");
            Console.ReadKey();
```

How do I change the property?  Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to set the `wb.ItemStyle` with the item styles template name.

Examples:

```
wb.ItemStyle = "Default";
wb.ItemStyle = "ImageLeft";
```

It does not understand the display names of the item styles.

[MSND page explaining the different ItemStyles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447557%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Comment: Should I look in the ItemStyle.xsl file from the Style Library to get the name?

Comment: @users1100 Yes.

Comment: I went through the file but did not find any template name having Title and Description.

Comment: I did one thing to find the name of Title and Description. I exported the web part after setting the Title and Description manually and checked the ItemStyle property. It was displaying the name i.e.`NoImage`. I assigned in `wp.ItemStyle` but how to assign the individual values?

Comment: I mean that template is assigned but how to assign Title=Title and Description=Editor ? @Daniel Ziga

Comment: @users1100 "Title and description" is just the display name of the XSL template. I've updated my answer to include a link to an MSDN page which describes which templates contains what.

Comment: Yes sir, I understood what you said previously, the template name of "Title and Description" is `NoImage` I assigned it in my code. But I want to assign column names in "Title" and "Description".

Comment: @users1100 Oh, my bad. I'm not quite sure, but I think that `wb.SystemFields` or `wb.FilterDisplayValue` would be a good hint.

Comment: Ok, I am trying these properties.

Comment: Sir,I am not getting exact idea regarding to assign the values to properties, will you please provide some code or reference that what these properties actually mean?